# get Jenkins instance from bare groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-api

I'm trying to calling Jenkins API from bare groovy script ( in local environment ) instead of `https://jenkins.domain.com/script`.

Now I can successful import Jenkins libs as below:

```
@GrabResolver(name='jenkins', root='https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases')
@Grab(group='org.jenkins-ci.main', module='jenkins-core', version='2.377')
@Grab(group='org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow', module='workflow-api', version='1200.v8005c684b_a_c6')
@Grab(group='org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow', module='workflow-job', version='1254.v3f64639b_11dd')
@Grab(group='org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow', module='workflow-step-api', version='639.v6eca_cd8c04a_a_')

import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import hudson.Util
import hudson.model.Job
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob

String rootUrl  = 'https://my.jenkins.com'
String username = 'admin'
String password = 'admin'

// .. how to new a Jenkins instance here ..
// i.e.: Jenkins jenkins = new Jenkins.instance( url, username, password )

// list all workflowjobs
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems( WorkflowJob.class ).collect { it.fullName }
```

I'd like to know how I can `new` a jenkins instance by using url similar to run `jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.xxx`

---

btw, I've tried the [java-client-api](https://github.com/jenkinsci/java-client-api) as below, however it cannot identify `AbstractItem.class`, `WorkflowJob.class`, etc... is there any solution to "convert" `com.offbytwo.jenkins.JenkinsServer` to `jenkins.model.Jenkins` ?

```
@GrabResolver(name='jenkins', root='https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases')
@Grab(group='org.jenkins-ci.main', module='jenkins-core', version='2.377')
@Grab(group='com.offbytwo.jenkins', module='jenkins-client', version='0.3.8')

import com.offbytwo.jenkins.JenkinsServer

String rootUrl  = 'https://my.jenkins.com'
String username = 'admin'
String password = 'admin'

JenkinsServer jenkins = new JenkinsServer( new URI(rootUrl), username, password )
jenkins.getJobs()
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution is kinda off topic. however it indeed execute the groovy script locally.

- by using [api](https://marslo.github.io/ibook/jenkins/api.html)

  ```bash
  $ SERVER='localhost'
  $ COOKIEJAR="$(mktemp)"
  # get crumb issue
  $ CRUMB=$(curl -u "admin:admin" \
                 --cookie-jar "${COOKIEJAR}" \
                 "https://${SERVER}/crumbIssuer/api/json" |
                 jq -r '[.crumbRequestField, .crumb] | join(":")'
           )

  # execute /path/to/script.groovy
  $ curl -u "admin:admin" \
         --cookie "${COOKIEJAR}" \
         -H "${CRUMB}" \
         -d "script=$(< /path/to/script.groovy)" \
         https://${SERVER}/scriptText
  ```
- by using [cli](https://marslo.github.io/ibook/jenkins/cli.html#execute-groovy-script-via-cli)

  - after setup [the environment](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/cli/)
  - execute `/path/to/script.groovy`:

    ```bash
    $ ssh -l <username> -p <port> -i <identityFile> ${SERVER} groovy =< ./path/to/script.groovy
    ```
  - if setup `~/.ssh/config`, it will be simpler as:

    ```bash
    $ ssh ${SERVER} groovy =< /path/to/script.groovy
    ```
  - i.e.:
    [image]